# Как сделать XPATH запрос с несколькими элементами?

Tags: xpath

Загружаю https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=music
Пытаюсь с помощью XPATH запроса:

```
//h3[@class='title-and-badge style-scope ytd-video-renderer']
```

найти строку:

```
<a id="video-title" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" title="Best songs to boost your mood ~ Chill vibes  Chill out music mix playlist" href="/watch?v=E4KMnaOF7lU" aria-label="Best songs to boost your mood ~ Chill vibes  Chill out music mix playlist by Chilled Feelings 14 hours ago 56 minutes 42,032 views">
```

Но находит только:[image: скрин]

Как изменить XPATH чтоб находил в выдаче сразу **title="" href="" aria-label=""**
и желательно чтоб ставил между ними разделитель, например такой @@@ .

Должно получится что-то вроде этого: **Best songs to boost your mood ~ Chill vibes  Chill out music mix playlist** @@@ **/watch?v=E4KMnaOF7lU** @@@ **Best songs to boost your mood ~ Chill vibes  Chill out music mix playlist by Chilled Feelings 14 hours ago 56 minutes 42,032 views**

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код, которым делаете запрос и обрабатываете результат.

Comment: с помощью этого XPATH: //h3[@class='title-and-badge style-scope ytd-video-renderer']

я пытаюсь выдрать из поиска название каждого видео, название видео, как давно было опубликовано видео, сколько просмотров. Всё это содержится в этом элемента <a>:
<a id="video-title" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" title="Best songs to boost your mood ~ Chill vibes  Chill out music mix playlist" href="/watch?v=E4KMnaOF7lU" aria-label="Best songs to boost your mood ~ Chill vibes  Chill out music mix playlist by Chilled Feelings 14 hours ago 56 minutes 42,032 views">

Comment: но мой xpath запрос выдаёт только название всех видео из поиска, а нужно чтоб он выдавал для каждого видео: название, как давно было опубликовано видео, сколько просмотров

Comment: может это можно сделать с помощью JS , как-то очистив код страницы . и оствить только нужно. Но я в JS не силён